# Common support with multiple treatments

Tags: econometrics, propensity-scores, cross-section

I want to use for my analysis propensity scoring. In the case of a binary treatment, one can restrict estimation to individuals in the region of common support in a straightforward manner using the minima and maxima criterion.

Is this approach valid for multiple treatments? I am asking because if there are say 6 treatments, then using a multinomial model we obtain 6 different propensity scores.

Also could someone explain how i can use the minima and maxima criterion (if valid) in this case to identify the region of common support among individuals in all treatment levels?